# How to isolate spring component class level variable across multiple threads

Tags: spring, multithreading

Having service (spring component- singleton scope) class with a class variable in multithreaded environment. Problem here is ,each thread modifies the class variable since the service class is singleton. How to handle this

Comment: Don't use class variables.

Comment: Is there anyway to handle this situation or any alternatives?

Comment: If you have a specific problem, you should add the relevant code and description to your question. Then we might be able to give proper suggestions. Right now, my first comment is the only proper solution to your question.

Comment: You can try to use ThreadLocal to keep the class.

Comment: Thanks StanislavL and dunni. Will check if threadlocal fits in